# Making an array of part of a vector in numpy

Tags: python

Is there a way to make a Python array in numpy of part of a vector? For example, say I have a vector v of length n, could I make an array of the elements v[2] to v[n-2]? I tried:

numpy.array(v[2]:v[n-2])

but this didn't work...

Comment: This should be in [SO]. There you sure will get an answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So i gues, you want the original array without the first and last element?         If so, then you just need to use 'slicing' , that means  just try                 'new_v=v[1,n-1]'.